# Thermostat wiring identification - missing yellow wire/extra wires

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

[image]Help please and apologies in advance for lack of technical knowledge! I'm looking to replace my old Honeywell 8022C 24v thermostat with a Nest, and have failed on several levels now I've taken a look at the existing wiring. The internet doesn't seem to know the answer so hoping someone has a spark of genius! Furnace is a Rheem rbhp-17j06sh1.

Wired to Honeywell:

There is a 4 wire multiwire - red, green and white are all connected to the expected RC, G & W terminals, with a jumper between RC and RH.

The multiwire has a blue wire which is currently attached via an acorn nut to a separate thick copper red wire (so not wired to thermostat - and it can't be seen in the photo).

The multiwire doesn't have a yellow wire; there is another separate thick copper wire which has been wired to the Y terminal on the existing terminal.

So, my questions are: Is the blue wire the C wire? If I wire it to the C terminal (which I would do if I install a Nest), what do I do with the copper red wire it's currently attached to? I don't know where that wire goes, so if I need to find out, suggestions on how I do that very helpful!

The other red wire currently wired to the Y terminal is too thick to fit the Nest Y terminal...are there any solutions for this?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Existing wiring]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler please?

Comment: Just added, thank you for replying!

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your air-handler for that matter, or at least a make and model number? (There should be labeling on the inside of the access panel or somewhere around the compartment -- you'll want to have the air-handler turned off at the breaker box when you're nosing around inside it, of course)

Comment: I realised that afterwards, but thank you! The model Rheem rbhp-17j06sh1

Comment: Just in case anyone ever has the same problem, I had an electrician come over today: Added an adaptor to change the thick wire going into Y into a thin wire (sorry for the lack of technical speak) and wired to thermostat, wired the blue C wire to the thermostat, and taped off the old thick wire it used to be attached to. Nest up and running!

Comment: If you could post that as an answer, especially with a diagram of how your electrician hooked things up, that'd be wonderful and get you an upvote from me :)

Comment: Ah well, I spoke too soon....on 'cool', the fan works but no cooling. I have an engineer coming back over the weekend so I will update. Assuming the Florida heat doesn't get to me first!